# URL details lost

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, url, browser, webbrowser-control

i used to call the browser_Navigating event twice, to enable UserAgent - switches for WP7. everything's working fine, but for example the user-input in loginboxes are missing. I experienced this on facebook, dunno if anything else affected.

heres the piece of code:

```
 private void Browser_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        var browser = sender as WebBrowser;

        if (UAnaviCounter < 1)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            browser.Navigate(e.Uri, null, UserAgent);
            UAnaviCounter++;
            return;
        }
...
}
```

anybody got an idea where the data could be lost?

thanks

Comment: `Url Fragment` bug was fixed in Mango. Do you still have issues with `Url Fragment` or something other details `Url` are lost?

Comment: the login is completely lost. just noticed that on facebook, but I don't know how I should solve that. how is the webpage working with the input? Is it somewhere contained in the url if it was successful oder a failure?

Comment: Is it really passed in `Url`. What says traffic sniffer, such as Fiddler?

Comment: it's the javascipt part. It's POST and not GET, so I can't handle it. thanks anyway

Comment: @roqstr by the way, you pass the useragent, and it'll work for that pass and only that pass. when a user clicks a link, unless you are intercepting every single link click, the useragent for the following requests will not carry on, also, any embedded iframes or frames will not get this new useragent that you've provided. Same deal for images and .css, .js and other LINK files and picture files that are loaded (not even on requests with the useragent specified) since the useragent isn't carried on for any other items apart from the html page you're calling in the e.Uri. Are you aware of this?